# Selecting form with SUBSTR

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table with name and profession I need to select the name of all employees with the first letter of their profession surrounded by () to be like:

```
Sara (D)
Jack (E)
```

Comment: SELECT name, CONCAT(SUBSTR(OCCUPATION,1,1)) FROM OCCUPATIONS order by name ASC;

Comment: here's a hint: don't use `CONCAT` - it's very limited, since it only accepts 2 parameters. Instead, used the concatenation symbol `||` which allows you to concatenate multiple parts together. Here's another hint: You're trying to concatenate the name column, a space and open bracket, the first letter of the occupation, and a close bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `||` to concatenate strings and `SUBSTR()` to get the first character:

```
SELECT name || ' (' || SUBSTR( profession, 1,, 1 ) || ')'
FROM   your_table;
```